# Как использовать целую строчку

Tags: python

Я ввожу текст "раз два три" и при добавлении его к ссылке [https://blabla.com/search={text}](https://blabla.com/search=%7Btext%7D)
получаю на выходе [https://blabla.com/search=раз](https://blabla.com/search=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7) два три. А нужно [https://blabla.com/search=раз&20два&20три](https://blabla.com/search=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7&20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0&20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8)

Как я могу сделать запрос единым ?

Answer (score 1):

'раз два три'.replace(' ' , '&20')

Answer (score 1):

Ну по-нормальному нужно использовать функции пакета `urllib`, предназначенные специально для этих целей:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, urljoin
 
print(urljoin('https://blabla.com/', urlencode({'search': 'раз два три'})))
```

Вывод:

```
https://blabla.com/search=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8
```

При переходе по этой ссылке пробелы и русские буквы раскодируются обратно автоматически.

Answer (score 1):

я бы сделал так:

```
text = " раз     два три   "
result = f'https://blabla.com/search={"&20".join(text.split())}'
print(result)
```

при такой реализации (в отличии от `.replace` несколько пробелов все равно будут заменены одним `&20` и не будет пробелов в начале и конце строки

если же кол-во пробелов важно, то тогда сделал бы так:

```
text = " раз     два три   "
result = f'https://blabla.com/search={text.replace(" ", "&20")}'
print(result)
```

Comment: По-хорошему не нужно "вручную" работать с `url`, также как "вручную" парсить `html`. Для этого специальные средства есть. Там слишком много тонкостей.

Comment: не спорю, поэтому ваш пример более точен